# Não estou conseguindo pegar o id Fullcalendar V4

Tags: fullcalendar

Não estou recebendo os valores quando clico no compromisso.
Eu sempre recebo "Indefinido"
Alguém pode me dizer o que estou fazendo errado ..?
Muito Obrigado.

Eu fiz esse exemplo no CODEPEN caso alguém queira ver o problema ao vivo.
https://codepen.io/egameiro/pen/Rwbgemx

Veja abaixo meu código.

```js
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid'],
  defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',

  locale: 'pt-br',
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
  },
  navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
  selectable: true,
  selectHelper: true,
  //selectMirror: true,
  editable: true,
  eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

  //events: event1,
  events: [{
    id: '10',
    title: 'Meeting',
    start: '2019-08-01T10:30:00',
    end: '2019-08-01T12:30:00'
  }],

  eventClick: function (event) {
    alert(event.id);
    alert(event.title);
    alert(event.start.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
    return false;
  },



});

calendar.render();
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, para funcionar você precisa remover as aspas do id, assim como no exemplo :

```js
  events: [{
    id: 10,
    title: 'Meeting',
    start: '2019-08-01T10:30:00',
    end: '2019-08-01T12:30:00'
  }]
```